# How do you edit an expression on the right to accommodate the removal of a square root on the left.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics

The $\sqrt{Z}$ is a multiplier for the constant on the right, how can I rewrite the constant to remove the square root from the multiplier and make the multiplier just $Z$? $\sqrt{Z}*(\frac{2\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{SG}}}{\pi r^2})$

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I made the edits. and this is just a single expression.

Answer (score 1):

Changing from $\sqrt{Z}$ to Z on the left, you are multiplying by $\sqrt{Z}$.  To correct for that you need to divide by $\sqrt{Z}$ on the right:$Z\left(\frac{2\sqrt{\frac{h}{SG}}}{\pi r^2\sqrt{Z}}\right)$.

If by "constant" you meant "not depending on Z" there is no way to keep that constant.

Comment: What happened I needed to find the density from this expression here which is just mass/volume ${\frac{{\sqrt{\frac {\hbar{\frac{Z}{S}} }{4G}}} *r} {{\frac {3}{4}}\pi r^3}}$. Then I needed to make the density a constant that was dependent on some multiple of $Z$. However it produced $\sqrt{Z}$ which I could not use. $\sqrt{Z}\frac{2\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{SG}}}{\pi r^2}$

Comment: Also, why did you state - "If by "constant" you meant "not depending on Z" there is no way to keep that constant."? This term $\left(\frac{2\sqrt{\frac{h}{SG}}}{\pi r^2\sqrt{Z}}\right)$ should be a proportionally term based on the some multiple of $Z$ right?

Comment: @Aneikei "Then I needed to make the density a constant that was dependent on some multiple of $Z$." Why do you think you needed this? I think you have misled yourself. I think you are trying to fit a round peg in a square hole, and instead you should look for the round hole where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

We can get rid of the $Z$-radical alone but not the corresponding radical for the expression as a whole.

Given  $\quad \left(\dfrac{2\sqrt{\dfrac{\hbar}{SG}}}{\pi r^2}\right)
= \dfrac{2\sqrt{h}}{\pi r^2\sqrt{SG}} = C
\quad \text{The expression yields a constant  value  C.} $

$$\dfrac{2\sqrt{h}}{\pi r^2\sqrt{SG}}=C
\implies \sqrt{Z}\dfrac{2\sqrt{h}}{\pi r^2\sqrt{SG}}=\sqrt{Z}C$$

$$\sqrt{Z}C\space = \space \sqrt{ZC^2}
=\sqrt{Z\bigg(\dfrac{2\sqrt{h}}{\pi r^2\sqrt{SG}}\bigg)^2}$$